# Can you physically connect an FPC to a FFC socket that has the same pitch but more circuits?

Tags: connector, prototyping, breakout, fpc

I'm interested if it's possible to make a **50 pin** FPC **breakout board** and use it for cables of **less pin count** but of the **same pitch**?

Comment: too many acronyms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Physically, yes, you can.

But, electrically, the FPC is likely to be misaligned in the FFC socket, therefore either shorting adjacent circuits or not making any contact.

So, not advisable.

Instead, place multiple sockets in your breakout boards, sockets with different pin counts.